# C# how to rename Excel Sheet using Interop

Tags: c#, excel

I need to create an Excel spreadsheet and then I need to rename the sheets. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class CreateExcelWorksheet
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

        oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
        oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

        oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "First Name";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Last Name";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Full Name";
        oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Salary";

        //Format A1:D1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
        oSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
        oSheet.Name = "NewOne";

        string filename = "C:\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yy_hhmmss");
        oWB.SaveAs(filename + "asdaa" + ".xlsx");

        oWB.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`oWB.Worksheets` is where you find the sheets.

Can take them by index `Worksheets[1]` (or 2, or 3...)

Can take them by name `Worksheets["SheetName"]`

They come as object, so cast them to `(Worksheet)`.

```
Worksheet oSheet = (Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets["TheSheetYouWant"];
```

To change name: `oSheet.Name = "NewName";`

Comment: Elegant answer !

Answer (score 8):

Even shorter:
`workbook.Worksheets[1].Name = "Sheet Name";`

Comment: Cool, this is probably using `dynamic` variables. At the time I wrote my answer I was using .NET 3, so everything should be explicitly typed.